# Client-Server 2 way communication unsuccessful (Perl)

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming, client-server

**REQ FLOW :**

```
____________      LOGIN           ___________
|          |------------------->>|          |
|  CLIENT  |      LOGIN ACK      |  SERVER  |
|__________|<<------------------ |__________|
```

The client and the server sends across the contents of the files they open.

**CODE:**

***SERVER***

```
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( LocalHost => '127.0.0.1', LocalPort => '0155', Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 1, Reuse => 1 ) or die "Oops: $! \n";

print "Waiting for the Client.\n";

while($clientsocket = $socket->accept()){


print   "Connected from : ", $clientsocket->peerhost();
print   ", Port : ", $clientsocket->peerport(), "\n";

while(<$clientsocket>){
    if($_ ne "\$END\$\n"){
            print"Message received from Client : $_";
        print $clientsocket $_;
}
    else{
    print"\$END\$\n";  
}   
} last;
}

login_ack();
sub login_ack{

# Some code removed for the purpose of posting                          
open (LOGINACK, "login_ack.txt") || die "Cannot open login acknowledgment file $!\n";
my @loginack=<LOGINACK>;
close LOGINACK;                         
open(LOG, ">>logfile.txt");

foreach $loginack(@loginack) {
    if($loginack ne "\$END\$\n"){
        print $clientsocket $loginack;
        print LOG $loginack;
        print $loginack;
    }
    else{
        print"\$END\$\n";   
    }
}
```

***CLIENT***

```
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( PeerHost => '127.0.0.1', PeerPort => '0155', Proto => 'tcp', Reuse => 1) or die "$!\n";

print "Connected to the Server.\n";

send_login();
sub send_login{

# Some code removed for the purpose of posting                              
open (LOGIN, "Login.txt") || die "Cannot open login file $!\n";
my @login=<LOGIN>;
close LOGIN;                            
open(LOG, ">>logfile.txt");

foreach $login(@login) {
     if($login ne "\$END\$\n"){
        print $socket $login;
        print LOG $login;
        print $login;
    }
    else{
    print"\$END\$\n"; 
    }
}
} 
LOGINACK : while(<$socket>){
        print"Message received from Server : $_";
        print $socket $_; 
        last LOGINACK;
}
```

**PRESENT OUTPUT:**

[image]

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

***CLIENT***

```
Connected to the Server.
this is Login
SAS4
50
SAS_ACTION LOGIN
LOGIN bss
PASSWORD cleint
$END$
Message received from Server : this is Login Ack
Message received from Server : SAS4
Message received from Server : 61
Message received from Server : SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
Message received from Server : ACK_STATUS 0
Message received from Server : ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
Message received from Server : $END$
```

***SERVER***

```
Waiting for the Client.
Connected from : 127.0.0.1, Port : 1862
Message received from Client : this is Login
Message received from Client : SAS4
Message received from Client : 50
Message received from Client : SAS_ACTION LOGIN
Message received from Client : LOGIN bss
Message received from Client : PASSWORD cleint
Message received from Client : $END$
this is Login Ack
SAS4
61
SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
ACK_STATUS 0
ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
$END$
```

Comment: By the way, `while (...) { ...; last }` is a silly way of writing `if (...) { ... }`

Comment: IO::Socket::INET->new returns the error in `$@`, not `$!`.

Comment: Are you really running your server on privileged port `0155` (which is octal; the port number is 109 decimal)?  So you're running as `root`?  Ick, and likewise yuck!  Especially while you're developing, use a non-privileged port (number bigger than 1023) and don't run as root unless you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Revised Edition of Answer

This code includes 3 scripts:

1. `serverJ.pl` which is an iterative server, processing one request at a time, but continuing to process multiple requests;
2. `clientJ.pl` which is a simple client that sends the login request from the `Login.txt` file and echoes what it receives from the server; and
3. `clientQ.pl` which sends a QUIT message to the server.

I've left the code using old-fashioned file handles rather than upgrading to modern lexical file handles, but I changed to the 3-argument form of `open`.  One other change is that most messages are prefixed with `$$:`, the Perl process ID.  I would not have labelled the `INNER:` loop except for symmetry with the `OUTER:` loop, which does need a label.  It is not clear that the functions `send_login()` and `abc()` are needed in `clientJ.pl`; they are left in deference to the original code.

#### serverJ.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '1055',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 1,
    Reuse => 1
) or die "Oops: $! \n";

print "$$: waiting for clients.\n";
server_loop();
$socket->close();

sub server_loop
{
OUTER:
    while (my $clientsocket = $socket->accept())
    {
        print "$$: connected from : ", $clientsocket->peerhost();
        print ", port : ", $clientsocket->peerport(), "\n";

INNER:
        while (<$clientsocket>)
        {
            print"$$: Message received from Client : $_";
            last INNER if ($_ eq "\$END\$\n");
            last OUTER if ($_ eq "\$QUIT\$\n");
            print $clientsocket $_;
        }

        my $login_ack = "login_ack.txt";
        open LOGINACK, '<', $login_ack or die "Cannot open login acknowledgment file $login_ack ($!)\n";
        my @loginack = <LOGINACK>;
        close LOGINACK;

        my $logfile = "logfile.txt";
        open LOG, ">>", $logfile or die "$$: cannot open $logfile ($!)\n";

        foreach my $loginack (@loginack)
        {
            last if ($loginack eq "\$END\$\n");
            print $clientsocket $loginack;
            print LOG "$$: $loginack";
            print "$$: server to client: $loginack";
        }

        close LOG;
        close $clientsocket;
    }
}
```

#### clientJ.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort => '1055',
    Proto    => 'tcp',
    Reuse    => 1
) or die "$!\n";

print "$$: connected to the server.\n";

send_login();
abc();
$socket->close();

sub send_login
{
    my $login_txt = "Login.txt";
    open LOGIN, '<', $login_txt or die "Cannot open $login_txt $!\n";
    my @login = <LOGIN>;
    close LOGIN;

    my $logfile = "logfile.txt";
    open LOG, '>>', $logfile or die "Cannot open $logfile ($!)\n";

    foreach my $login (@login)
    {
        print $socket $login;
        print LOG "$$: $login";
        print "$$: sent to server: $login";
        last if ($login eq "\$END\$\n");
    }
    close LOG;
}

sub abc
{
    while (<$socket>)
    {
        print"$$: Message received from Server: $_";
    }
}
```

#### clientQ.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
  PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
  PeerPort => '1055',
  Proto    => 'tcp',
  Reuse    => 1
) or die "$!\n";

print $socket "\$QUIT\$\n";

$socket->close();
```

#### Sample log

```
$ perl serverJ.pl 2>&1 &
[1] 87610
$ 87610: waiting for clients.

$ perl clientJ.pl | so
87610: connected from : 127.0.0.1, port : 57143
87610: Message received from Client : SAS4
87610: Message received from Client : 50
87610: Message received from Client : SAS_ACTION LOGIN
87610: Message received from Client : LOGIN bss
87610: Message received from Client : PASSWORD cleint
87610: Message received from Client : $END$
87610: server to client: SAS4
87610: server to client: 61
87610: server to client: SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
87610: server to client: ACK_STATUS 0
87610: server to client: ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
87614: connected to the server.
87614: sent to server: SAS4
87614: sent to server: 50
87614: sent to server: SAS_ACTION LOGIN
87614: sent to server: LOGIN bss
87614: sent to server: PASSWORD cleint
87614: sent to server: $END$
87614: Message received from Server: SAS4
87614: Message received from Server: 50
87614: Message received from Server: SAS_ACTION LOGIN
87614: Message received from Server: LOGIN bss
87614: Message received from Server: PASSWORD cleint
87614: Message received from Server: SAS4
87614: Message received from Server: 61
87614: Message received from Server: SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
87614: Message received from Server: ACK_STATUS 0
87614: Message received from Server: ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
$ perl clientJ.pl | so
87610: connected from : 127.0.0.1, port : 57144
87610: Message received from Client : SAS4
87610: Message received from Client : 50
87610: Message received from Client : SAS_ACTION LOGIN
87610: Message received from Client : LOGIN bss
87610: Message received from Client : PASSWORD cleint
87610: Message received from Client : $END$
87610: server to client: SAS4
87610: server to client: 61
87610: server to client: SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
87610: server to client: ACK_STATUS 0
87610: server to client: ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
87617: connected to the server.
87617: sent to server: SAS4
87617: sent to server: 50
87617: sent to server: SAS_ACTION LOGIN
87617: sent to server: LOGIN bss
87617: sent to server: PASSWORD cleint
87617: sent to server: $END$
87617: Message received from Server: SAS4
87617: Message received from Server: 50
87617: Message received from Server: SAS_ACTION LOGIN
87617: Message received from Server: LOGIN bss
87617: Message received from Server: PASSWORD cleint
87617: Message received from Server: SAS4
87617: Message received from Server: 61
87617: Message received from Server: SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
87617: Message received from Server: ACK_STATUS 0
87617: Message received from Server: ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
$ perl clientQ.pl | so
87610: connected from : 127.0.0.1, port : 57147
87610: Message received from Client : $QUIT$
[1]+  Done                    perl serverJ.pl 2>&1
$
```

---

#### Post loop code executes

> In the server script, while sending the acknowledgement, the code after the `foreach my $loginack (@loginack)` loop does not get executed. I think that is because the code cannot break out of the loop. How shall it be dealt with?

Mildly modified code in `serverJ.pl`:

```
        foreach my $loginack (@loginack)
        {
            last if ($loginack eq "\$END\$\n");
            print $clientsocket $loginack;
            print LOG "$$: $loginack";
            print "$$: server to client: $loginack";
        }

        print "$$: End of Loop\n";
        close LOG;
        close $clientsocket;
        print "$$: After close\n";
```

Example run:

```
$ perl serverJ.pl &
[1] 6913
$ 6913: waiting for clients.

$ perl clientJ.pl
6915: connected to the server.
6913: connected from : 127.0.0.1, port : 52454
6915: sent to server: This is the file Login.txt
6913: Message received from Client : This is the file Login.txt
6915: sent to server: It contains more than 1 line
6915: sent to server: It also contains this one
6915: sent to server: $END$
6913: Message received from Client : It contains more than 1 line
6913: Message received from Client : It also contains this one
6913: Message received from Client : $END$
6915: Message received from Server: This is the file Login.txt
6915: Message received from Server: It contains more than 1 line
6915: Message received from Server: It also contains this one
6913: server to client: This is the file login_ack.txt
6913: server to client: As with the other file, it contains multiple lines
6913: server to client: Several of them.
6913: server to client: This is one of them.
6915: Message received from Server: This is the file login_ack.txt
6913: End of Loop
6915: Message received from Server: As with the other file, it contains multiple lines
6915: Message received from Server: Several of them.
6915: Message received from Server: This is one of them.
6913: After close
$ perl clientQ.pl
6913: connected from : 127.0.0.1, port : 52455
6913: Message received from Client : $QUIT$
[1]+  Done                    perl serverJ.pl
$
```

---

## Original Edition of Answer

This code seems to work for me (for a loose definition of 'works').  It is closely based on your code, but using socket 1055 instead of 0155 (I run on Unix; I'd have to be root to use a port number less than 1024), and with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and other minor cleanups.

#### server.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET( LocalHost => '127.0.0.1', LocalPort => '1055', Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 1, Reuse => 1 ) or die "Oops: $! \n";

print "Waiting for the Client.\n";

my $clientsocket;

while ($clientsocket = $socket->accept())
{
    print   "Connected from : ", $clientsocket->peerhost();
    print   ", Port : ", $clientsocket->peerport(), "\n";

    while (<$clientsocket>)
    {
        if ($_ ne "\$END\$\n")
        {
            print"Message received from Client : $_";
            print $clientsocket $_;
        }
        else
        {
            print"\$END\$\n";  
        }   
    }
    last;
}

login_ack();

sub login_ack
{
    # Some code removed for the purpose of posting                          
    open (LOGINACK, "login_ack.txt") || die "Cannot open login acknowledgment file $!\n";
    my @loginack=<LOGINACK>;
    close LOGINACK;                         
    open(LOG, ">>logfile.txt");

    foreach my $loginack (@loginack)
    {
        if ($loginack ne "\$END\$\n")
        {
            print $clientsocket $loginack;
            print LOG $loginack;
            print $loginack;
        }
        else
        {
            print"\$END\$\n";   
        }
    }
}
```

#### client.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( PeerHost => '127.0.0.1', PeerPort => '1055', Proto => 'tcp', Reuse => 1) or die "$!\n";

print "Connected to the Server.\n";

send_login();

sub send_login
{
# Some code removed for the purpose of posting                              
    open (LOGIN, "Login.txt") || die "Cannot open login file $!\n";
    my @login=<LOGIN>;
    close LOGIN;                            
    open(LOG, ">>logfile.txt");

    foreach my $login (@login)
    {
        if ($login ne "\$END\$\n")
        {
            print $socket $login;
            print LOG $login;
            print $login;
        }
        else
        {
            print"\$END\$\n"; 
        }
    }
} 

LOGINACK:
while (<$socket>)
{
    print"Message received from Server : $_";
    print $socket $_; 
    last LOGINACK;
}
```

#### Login.txt

```
This is the content of the Login.txt file.
$END$
```

#### login_ack.txt

```
This is the contents of the login_ack.txt file.
It has two lines of text plus the $END$ line.
$END$
```

#### Sample output

```
$ perl server.pl &
[1] 74838
$ Waiting for the Client.

$ perl client.pl | so
Connected from : 127.0.0.1, Port : 51109
Message received from Client : This is the content of the Login.txt file.
Message received from Client : This is the content of the Login.txt file.
Connected to the Server.
This is the content of the Login.txt file.
$END$
Message received from Server : This is the content of the Login.txt file.
This is the contents of the login_ack.txt file.
It has two lines of text plus the $END$ line.
$END$
[1]+  Done                    perl server.pl
$
```

The server terminates after responding to a single request.

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for having a look at the code,
but your variant of th code yields the exact same output as the one ive put up. Like 100pc. Also, regarding the use strict, use warnings, i used it in the actual code, for the purpose of posting it here, the SSCCE thing you taught me, i removed it.

Comment: An SSCCE is complete; the `use` statements are part of the completeness.  People are apt to comment on the absence of `use strict` and `use warnings` so it is best to include them to head off trouble.  The shebang line is perhaps optional; I'd include it — as shown.

Comment: In the server script, while sending the acknowledgement, the code after the 'foreach my $loginack (@loginack)' loop does not get executed. I think that is because the code cannot break out of the loop. How shall it be dealt?

Comment: The `foreach my $loginack (@loginack)` cannot be an infinite loop, AFAIK (unless, perhaps, you extend the `@loginack` array on each iteration of the loop).  It executes once per entry in the `@loginack` array.  In the code in the question, there is no code shown after the foreach loop.  In `serverJ.pl`, I don't see a way for the loop to be infinite; in `server.pl` (1st Edition of Answer), I still don't see a way for the loop to be infinite.  Add extra print statements.

Comment: As I though too.
Talking about the Revised Edition of the code,
if we add 'print"The line after the foreach code is printing";
before 'close LOG; close $clientsocket;' in the server.pl,
the line odes not get printed. 
Therefore, no code after this code gets executed.

Comment: I've tested a modified version of the `serverJ.pl` script and the loop terminates fine.  See trace information in edited answer.

Comment: There was no substantive change; I just added the two debug print lines after the loop.

Comment: The question still remains, the code is not able to exit through the loops completely, from the while(<$clientsocket>) loop too. :/

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but the code is working fine for me.  If you are expecting `serverJ.pl` to be a single-cycle program (so it exits after the first client), then you need to re-read the notes I provided (see point 1 in the revised answer), and use the `clientQ.pl` to make it terminate.  Or modify the code so it stops after the first response, but that makes it a pointless server.

Comment: What needs to be done is that after the Login chunk, more chunk of code needs to be executed. It only can be done if the entire code is read. but if we test the code by putting print statements after the while loop, it does not print, meaning, it does not get off from that loop, the while(<$serverclient>) loop, and hence the sub Login.

Comment: Sincere thanks.. Its coz of you Jon that ive been able to work upon this so far. Really.

Comment: Apologies, the while loop that i was talking about was :
while (my $clientsocket = $socket->accept()), thats not being exited.

Answer (score 3):

`accept` is used to accept a connection from a `listen`ing (server) socket. Client sockets are connected by `connect`, which is called for you by `new`.

So,

```
while (my $serversocket = $socket->accept()) {
   print "\nThe line after the while loop is printing\n\n";
   while (<$serversocket>) {
      print "Message received from Server : $_";
      print $serversocket $_;
   }
}
```

should be

```
while (<$socket>) {
   print "Message received from Server : $_";
}
```

The output of the client is now

```
Connected to the Server.
SAS4
50
SAS_ACTION LOGIN
LOGIN bss
PASSWORD cleint
$END$

The line before the while loop is printing.

Message received from Server : SAS4
Message received from Server : 50
Message received from Server : SAS_ACTION LOGIN
Message received from Server : LOGIN bss
Message received from Server : PASSWORD cleint
Message received from Server : $END$
```

Then it waits for more input from the server. The server never calls `login_ack`, since it's waiting for more input from the client. When do you want to call `login_ack`?

Comment: the code is still not yielding the correct output.
1. In the client, the cmd reads out : Message from the Server : {The file that the is client is reading(Login)}.

2. In the server, the cmd reads out : Message from client : {The file that the client is reading(Login)} --> This is correct but contradicts (point 1).

3. The code in the client is running over and over again in a loop.

Comment: My Contradiction: we are not outputting the correct thing in Client. Instead of outputting the i/p from the Server, we are outputting the i/p from the client itself. Pls have a look. TY

Comment: It needs to be called as soon as we receive "$END$" from the client.

Comment: Ok, so you need to add a check to see if the line received is `$END$`.

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire code? Its merely some 50 lines each

Comment: There's no such `if`. And you should most definitely not post addition code! (Since I've updated it) what's posted is minimal runnable code to demonstrate the problem. That's exactly what should be posted. Like I just said, the only thing missing is a check to see if `$_` contains `"$END$\n"` Are you saying you do not know how to check what a variable contains?

Comment: I have been trying to put the if condition like so 
if($login ne "\$END\$"){ 
#-- 
}
havent been able to make it right. pls help me apply it
I know what ive applied is wrong.

Comment: You forgot about the newline. Either use `chomp` or compare against `"\$END\$\n"`

Comment: foreach $login(@login) {
     if($login ne "\$END\$\n"){
      print $socket $login;
      print LOG $login;
      print $login;
     }
     else{
      print"\$END\$\n"; 
      last;
     }
    }

Comment: No. Why would the client call `login_ack`? You're trying to call `login_ack` which you're not currently calling. You need to add a check to see if the line **received** by the **server** is `"\$END\$\n"`.

Comment: the client is running the loop over and over again. so if we check over there the outputting of "\$END\$\n", we shall get out of the loop. Right?

Comment: Yes, you would *also* want to check that in the client, but that's third previously unmentioned problem.